# create iOS universal framework (kstenerud) from existing project

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

i'm trying to create an iOS Framework (or a static library) for our customers to use. I'd like to create a Framework using the Framework tool found here: https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework

can i create the iOS framework from existing project ? because costumers want use our application and integrate into their application, so i can't give our code to costumer

any advice or the other ways ?

thanks.

Comment: What kind of project do you have?

Comment: what do you mean with kind of project ? sorry i'm newbie on obj c and Xcode

Comment: When you created the project, what kind of project did you select??

Comment: 2020, Check this repo as an alternative solution: https://github.com/gurhub/universal-framework